# How to use prefetch_related across mutliple one-to-many relations in Django?

Tags: python, django, one-to-many, prefetch

My goal is to use `prefetch_related` to obtain all my models and related models in one Django query, thus not hitting the database when iterating through related models.

Say I have the following models of Library having many Books having many Pages.

```
from django.db import models

class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Page(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I know I can do `models.Library.objects.prefetch_related('book_set__page_set')` to get everything one-shot, but what if I want to restrict to book with `genre='fantasy'`? How can I add this filter condition in my relation-spanning prefetch query?

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @themanatuf answer which was missing the prefetching of related Page models. Query code below will prefetch all Library models with their related Books and Pages, but restricting to Book genre='fantasy':

```
pf_queryset = models.Book.objects.filter(genre="fantasy").prefetch_related("page_set")
pf = Prefetch("book_set", queryset=pf_queryset)
models.Library.objects.prefetch_related(pf).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to follow the instructions here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects

Basically you'll do something like this

```py
books_query = Books.objects.filter(genre="fantasy")
pf = Prefetch("book_set", queryset=books_query)
Library.objects.prefetch_related(pf).get().book_set.all()
```

Comment: It's missing the prefetching of related Page models, 'book_set__page_set'